# How to apply animation on LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-animation, android-relativelayout

I'm wondering if there is a way to apply animation on `LayoutParams`. Here is the story.
Say I have the following layout, a `TextView` on the left top corner of a `RelativeLayout`.

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <TextView
        android:alignParentStart="true"
        android:alignParentTop="true"/>
    ...
<RelativeLayout />
```

Then I want to move the `TextView` to center of the `RelativeLayout` using animation. After the animation, the layout will become

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <TextView
        android:centerInParent="true"/>
    ...
<RelativeLayout />
```

Just wondering if there is a way to do it using `Animator`? Thanks.

Comment: Try inserting this to your `RelativeLayout` `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"`

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is position the `TexView` always at the center of his parent using `android:centerInParent="true"`, and using `ValueAnimator` or `ObjectAnimator` to animate the `width` and `height` of his parent.
Obviously it would be better if you can somehow calculate the width of the screen but for that i guess is enough to extend the layout parent class (`RelativeLayout`) and override his `onMeasure` or `onLayout` method.